# slide up view in iPad in landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am using slide-up view in ipad,But i am facing one problem that when i use button action on portrait mode then view is sliding up but when used in landscape mode that time its not working.
Please help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks
Kunal